# Searching a column with comma separated values

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, full-text-search, freetext

I have SQL server 2008 r2 edition, which am working on and a `.Net` webpage as front end.

Coming to the issue, there is a column in the database which basically consists of various skill sets separated by a comma. For example some candidate has a 3 different skill sets namely `C#`, `SQL server`, `Oracle`. The user who wants to list the candidates having the skills of both `C#` and `Oracle` will provide the input as `C#, Oracle` in a text box on the webpage. I want to write a query which can list out such. I have tried freetext search. But it fails to fetch if in Capital/small words, no support for wildcard character, even the order of skills.

Below is the sample query

```
Select * from profiles where freetext(skills, ‘C#,Oracle’)
```

Answer (score 11):

From my POV the correct (and unwelcome) answer is to redesign your table structure: You should never ever have a list of values in a single field, IF YOU WANT TO ACCESS THEM SEPARATELY.

Comment: @JonEgerton: Please be the one representative of the SO community to take my thanks for all of those guys who bother to fix my (non-native) english language errors. Much appreciated, and I learn my most common mistakes

Comment: Not a problem - your English is far better than my very basic German!

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: I agree with @EugenRieck (+1 to that answer) - stuffing a CSV string in one field is bad design.

But if you must...[look here first](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2000.html). Or [try a CLR solution](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#Split).

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/full-text-indexing-workbench/) is a good one about full-text.

Match **Both** C# and Oracle

```
select * From Profiles where contains(*,'"Oracle" and "C#"')
```

Match **Either** C# or Oracle

```
select * From Profiles where contains(*,'"Oracle" or "C#"')
```

[image: Full-text: and/or]