# SQL query to retrieve values from a comma separated column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)
>   [Searching a column with comma seperated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679376/searching-a-column-with-comma-seperated-values)

In my **PHP** project I'm facing a problem to write a SQL:

I have a table "**consultants**" with fields ***categories*** which has values like:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id |  consultant_name  | categories                           +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1 |  AOAOAO           | health,insurance,programming,        +
+  2 |  BOBOBO           | health,gaming,windows,mobile,        +
+  3 |  CCCCCC           | insurance,windows,                   + 
+  4 |  DDDDDD           | mobile,                              +
+  . |  ......           | ............                         +
+  . |  ......           | ............                         +
+  . |  ......           | ............                         +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And I have **an array which contains all the categories** that a consultant can register with.

```
$arrayOfCategories =  $array("health","insurance","programming",
                             "sports","gaming","windows","apple",
                             "mobile","astrology");
```

What I want is a *SQL Query that should give me an output* like:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ category      | occurrence  +    
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ health        | 2           +
+ insurance     | 2           +
+ programming   | 1           +
+ sports        | 0           +
+ gaming        | 1           +
+ windows       | 2           +
+ apple         | 0           +
+ mobile        | 2           +
+ astrology     | 0           +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated...

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: This is what called a bad database design.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh : Yes I agree with you. But what to do if changes were asked at the last time.

Comment: You're looking for the opposite of [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742093/split-string-into-multiple-rows-in-sql to transform your DB schema into something sane

Comment: You really should consider normalizing your consultants table. With this kind of table you'll always be in trouble!

Comment: Bad database design but interesting question ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad database design but interesting question, here it is my way to do (php code):

```
$arrayOfCategories =  $array("health","insurance","programming",
                             "sports","gaming","windows","apple",
                             "mobile","astrology");

 $count = count($arrayOfCategories);
 $query = "";
 for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
 {
   $value = $arrayOfCategories[$i];
   $query += "SELECT '$value' AS category,
                 COUNT(*) AS occurrence
                 FROM consultants
                 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$value', categories)";
    if($i < $count -1) {
    $query += " UNION "
    }


 }
```

The result of the generated query should give you exactly what you want . Often from a bad design comes interesting questions ... :)

Comment: Thanks dude, it is working perfectly as I wanted... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad database design. If I were stuck with it, I wouldn't try to use SQL to get the occurrences, but my application.

Create a new array called $occurence, this will have an index of each word and a count.
Select every row and split the contents of categories on the comma. Loop through this resulting array and increment for every word.

I'm a little rusty in PHP so here is my suggestion in Perl:

```
my %occurrence;

while ( my ($categories) = $sth->fetchrow_array() ){

   my @cats = split(',', $categories);

   foreach my $c (@cats){
      $occurrence{$c}++;
   }

}
```

One of the benefits of this way is you will find any mispelled categories and don't have to update your SQL when a new category gets added.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a table with categories, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT cat.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM categories cat JOIN consultants con ON con.categories LIKE '%'+cat.name+'%'
```

Still, I consider this awkward and you should consider normalising the db scheme so that there's a mapping table for the consultant-category relation

Comment: The query would of course fail if one category is a substring of the other

Comment: Not if it were `like '%,'+cat.name+',%'` and you ensure that `con.categories` had a comma at either end.

Comment: @Ben I know, I just don't think it's worth bothering as this is not a clever thing to do anyway...

Comment: I'd agree with you there! Spending the time to normalise the schema would save a lot more time in the long run